# Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 3 Unable to Adjust Backlight after Upgrading to Linux 5.10

Tags: linux-kernel, nvidia, manjaro, graphics, laptop

Today I saw a message suggesting to update to 5.10 kernel, and I happily did it, but now I cannot adjust my laptop's screen backlight.

On Linux 5.9, I adjust the backlight by writing to the file `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness`, and if I look at the `nvidia_0` directory, it's a symlink to another directory:

```
lrwxrwxrwx root root 0 B 5 minutes ago nvidia_0 ⇒ ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/nvidia_0
```

But when I boot using 5.10, my `/sys/class/backlight` directory is empty.

On Linux 5.9, I have the following when I search for `backlight` in `/sys/devices`:

```
pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight
platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight
```

But on Linux 5.10, I only have this:

```
platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight
```

I get this when I do `mhwd -li`:

```
Warning: config '/var/lib/mhwd/local/pci/video-nvidia-455xx/MHWDCONFIG' is invalid!
> Installed PCI configs:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  NAME               VERSION          FREEDRIVER           TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          video-nvidia            2020.11.30               false            PCI


Warning: No installed USB configs!
```

I'm not sure what the warning is about, but on 5.9, I also get the warning, and the backlight works